# Join two columns in lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, concatenation

I have a dataframe with 2 columns "first_name" and "name".

What I'm trying to do is check the length of first_name and if it is <=3 then create a new column "new_name" and concatenate the "first_name" and "name" columns. If the length is >3 then the new_name should be same as "first_name".

Example:

```
first_name   name      new_name
 V           David      VDavid
```

I tried doing this:

```
df = df.assign(new_name= lambda x: x.first_name + x.name if len(x.first_name) <= 3 else x.first_name)
```

This piece of code should do the trick but it's not working as expected. It's simply returning the first_name irrespective of the length of the word.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = df.assign(new_name= lambda x: np.where(x.first_name.str.len() <= 3, 
                                            x.first_name + x.name, 
                                            x.first_name))
```